# Methods for reliably benchmarking own program's run time

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, benchmarking

I'm writing a basic password cracker in C as an introduction to multithreaded programming. I've implemented this already using a 'parallelization' approach that spins up a set number of threads and divides the given wordlist among them, and every thread is more or less self contained to each other. Once one finds a password, the whole program is terminated.

For exercise sake though I also want to try implementing this in a 'pipeline' approach, where each 'stage' of the cracking process (for instance, password hashing, AES decryption, checksum verification etc) are all assigned their own dedicated threads, and each passes data to the next as they work through the wordlist. The problem here though is that if one stage of the pipeline is significantly faster or slower than the one before or after it, it could stall the whole pipeline waiting for new data.

I figured the best way to address this would be to somehow find a rough ratio of how long each stage of the pipeline takes the compute and then assign multiple threads to each one based on that. For example, if stage 1 takes roughly double the time of stage 2, then I could prevent stalling by assigning two threads to stage 1 and only 1 to stage 2.

The problem then is how to reliably figure out how long each stage is going to take to operate on a given piece of data in relation to the others. I'm not really too sure where to begin with this, currently my main idea is to use the clock function provided by time.h to get run times for specific functions, or maybe perf to get relative overhead for each function, but as I understand benchmarking is a very volatile process with lots of moving parts and it's difficult to get reliable results, let alone portable ones.

As this is just a toy program, portability isn't necessarily needed, perhaps though if I could get reliable results on one machine I could make some elaborate makefile to re-benchmark on every machine it's built on, but at the very least I would like to get accurate results on my own machine to test this style of multithreading.

Is there any established way to get results like these when pipelining is used in industry?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1794816

Comment: [This page](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-parallel-functional-pipeline-pattern/) contains a diagram that will help improve upon your current design. The basic idea is that it is not necessary for a thread to be restricted to implementing a single type of task. Instead, package a task (containing a package of data and a function pointer), push the package into a thread-safe queue, and then create a team of worker threads that consume from the queue and execute the task contained in each package.

Comment: This question can be broken down into these sub-questions: (1) in general, how does one implement a parallelized pipeline where the pipeline stages do not take equal amount of time to execute? (2) how do I collect high frequency execution timing from a CPU-intensive task (or, CPU-Memory-intensive; no I/O other than CPU or Memory)? (3) How do I ensure the high frequency timing samples are informative for my code-optimization pursuit? (4) Are there parallelization paradigms in general that improve upon the pipeline approach described here, without overfitting to the choice of my toy task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The time of each stage depends mainly on the operation that stage is performing. E.g. the password hashing stage will always hash one password and >99% of all CPU time will be spend on hashing, so just benchmark how many passwords you can hash a second and call this the stage score. Do the same thing with the AES decryption function, test how many data blocks you can decrypt a second. If your hashing stage score is twice as big as your decryption stage score, the hashing pipeline step is twice as fast.

To find out how many operations you can perform a second, just take the current system time as precisely as possible (doesn't have to be wallclock time, something like system uptime will work even better), perform a reasonable large number of operations, and finally take the same time again (any number will do but the larger it is, the more precise your benchmark result will be). The number of operations divided by the difference of the two time values gives you the number of operations per time unit. If the time unit is 1 ms, you have calculated the number of operations per millisecond which works as well (or transform it to operations per second if you like).

However, I think the problem is rather your general approach. It makes no sense to give every stage an own thread. Instead you should create a a bunch of threads, at least as many threads as the system has cores, yet it may be beneficial for overall performance to have 1-2 extra threads. Every thread runs the same code, which requests the next password to test at some central test manager, performs all the steps in a row (hashing, decrypting, checksum verification) and then reports the result back if it found the correct password or otherwise fetches the next one to test and starts from the beginning (a simple loop). As all threads will do that at the same time, you will always have optimal CPU utilization, something your design pattern cannot ever achieve.

And the only place in our code that requires to be thread-safe is the manager function that hands out the next password to test. The threads themselves work isolated and thus don't require any thread-safety and reporting the result also requires no thread-safety as only one thread can ever find a result (there is only one correct password and no two threads ever test the same password). To stop the threads, just hand out an empty password to them which is the signal for them to break out of the loop and stop running. That way you can easily stop the whole run when either one thread has found the correct password, when you ran out of passwords to test or when the user canceled the run.

Comment: Thanks for the advise on bench marking, this helps. I think though what you're describing as an alternate multi-threading approach is the version I mentioned I've already implemented, namely the 'parallelized' method where the wordlist is divided among however many threads are allocated and they each carry out the entire series of operations. I want to try benchmarking against the other approach though as I'm wondering if having specialized threads might increase cache utilization or perhaps even branch prediction, and again to get the learning experience implementing it at all.